# render conditional asp:content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to render a conditional asp:content
how can I do this please?

```
**if( culture=fr)**
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="altColumnContent" ID="altColContent" runat="server">
    <div class="altBloc">
     content 1
    </div>
    <!-- END: Alternative Bloc -->
</asp:Content>


  **if(culture=en)**
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="altColumnContent" ID="altColContent" runat="server">
    <div class="altBloc">
     content 2
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When, I put 2 asp:content with the same ContentPlaceHolderId i have erros.

regards

Comment: You could also use one `<asp:Content />` for both, and then use two different `<asp:Placeholder />`, which you show and hide using the `Visible` property (alternative approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the content based on the culture property value, then there is no need to render different content tags, and you better move the if statement inside your  and render different content inside based on the culture value?

this is a pseudo-block for demonstration

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="altColumnContent" ID="altColContent" runat="server">
    <div class="altBloc">
     <% if(CultureValue == FIRST_VALUE){ %>

           content 1 ==>   // YOUR_FIRST_CONTENT       

     <%} else { %>

           content 2 ==>   // YOUR_SECOND_CONTENT            
     <%} %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```